# Difference between corporate design and brand design?

Tags: website-design, design-principles, design-process

Hi guys I need your help! For a study project I have to change the appearance of a real company. Now it looks like the company A want to implement a new project. This should not adopt the design of company A. It should not be recognizable that company A is behind the project. For the project they want a logo, typography, colors, a website (online trade) etc..

Do I have to implement a corporate design or a brand design for this project? I don't quite understand the difference between corporate design and brand design yet.

From my understanding the term corporate means only entities, i.e. people who do something together, be it a company, an institution or any other organization. The brand on the other hand means not only companies but also products and other things.
So you could possibly see the project as "other things"? Then it's brand design, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brand Design**: The imagery used to identify a brand.... a la logo, mastheads, stationary, packaging, vehicle wraps, signage, uniforms, etc. Essentially anything which has the primary purpose of identifying the item as coming from the same entity.

**Corporate Design**: In terms of "graphic design", this is merely a **style** of design. "[Corporate](https://www.google.com/search?q=corporate%20design&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU7eLkn-_vAhWO_J4KHVcyAQoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1622&bih=1187)" often indicates a more upscale design style. Often minimalist, with a limited color palette, targeted at older, professional, economically secure, audiences in *broad* terms.

The two are not contradictory. One *can* design a brand which is based upon a more "corporate" style as oppose to a more "trendy" or "youthful" style.

For example, both of these *are* Brand Design:

[image]

The ToysRus brand is **not** a design with a corporate style.

[image] 
[image]

While the brand design for Charles Schwab could be said to be more corporate in style.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So what you're saying is that a corporate design is a subset of a brand design, right? Just in a more serious tone?

Comment: Hi @E.J Yes.. Brand design is the painting.. then corporate design would be like cubism, or impressionism, or art deco, or any number of "styles".